# Javap Asciz Strings

Tags: java, class, bytecode, javap

Little question about the output generated from the `javap` command regarding the constant pool.
When `javap` prints the pool it defines string constants as `Asciz` strings, which I understand means `null` terminated Ascii:

```
const #20 = Asciz       hello world;
```

This would imply that the length of the string is not known, and to parse you would read each byte until you encounter the `null`.

However, the length of constant pool string constants is defined by the two bytes preceding the string and there is no `null` appended. ([Constant pool specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#7963)).

Does `javap` define strings as `Asciz` incorrectly or does `Asciz` have another meaning I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [bug #6868539](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6868539). It's fixed in OpenJDK7, now `javap` prints `Utf8` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The const #20 is not the actual string, but rather the UTF8 defined characters used for your string. You probably have another constant which is a string that references the constant #20. The asciz constants are used for other things than strings such as field names etc. The actual info contains the UTF8 tag, the length and the bytes.

See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html

Comment: This is what I described in my short definition. You actually linked to the same reference as I did. The fact that it defines a UTF8 string, and not an ASCIZ string is what I was referring to.

Comment: Since there was no reference of null terminated ascii strings in the class file format specification I thought you meant how Strings were defined in the pool. (Even in the the 1.0 specification there are no ascii strings, but rather Unicode. None of them are null terminated). Jivings seemed to understand your question better than me.

Comment: Simply, what I wanted to know is why they are named Asciz in the constant pool when they are clearly not null terminated.